# What's the best way to offer a 1 month trial via Paypal (upfront or not)

Tags: paypal, subscriptions

I'm launching a SAS website with a monthly service charge and will be using Paypal to initiate payments. I want to offer a 30 day trial and then give clients the chance to start paying. The question is, should I embed the 30 day trial into Paypal subscription settings and have new users signup via Paypal upfront (as soon as they signup), or have signups use the site for 30 days without the Paypal part, then tell them that they need to do the Paypal part to continue using the site. I know this is more market research stuff, but thought some people might have a good idea what works best for subscription based websites. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

On the Paypal side, what you can do is create a simple subscription button via your Paypal account (Toolsd -> All Tools -> Paypal buttons) and in the creation form of your subscription button, you can specify a trial period, meanin gthat your customer will subscribe on your website, try it free for 1 month or the trial period you'll define, and then Paypal will automatically charge them whenever the trial period is over.
Hope those detials will help you in your decision.

Regards,
Florian